# How to create a Keras model with switchable input layers?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Current simple model:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 


def model():
    input_A = Input(shape=(6, ))
    out = Dense(64, activation="relu")(input_A)
    out = Dense(32, activation="relu")(out)
    outputs = Dense(1, activation="tanh")(out)  
    model = Model(
        inputs=input_A,
        outputs=outputs,
        name="switchable_inputs_model")
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model
```

I want to have *another* input layer `input_B` which will not be active all the time during learning. Let us say we have two input layers: `input A`, `input B`. However, at a given time, only one input layer can be active. This selection of input layer is decided by a binary combination of information available at the execution time(learning stage). For instance, if it is 1 0, then input layer A will be used. Similarly, if it is 0 1, input layer B will be used.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) (tl;dr: **no**). In this case, as this is an *implementation* question, it should be posted here, and not in AI SE.

Comment: Okay, this will be avoided in future.

Comment: No, not in the future, you can delete the question in AI SE.

Comment: This depends entirely on how the model is supposed to use the different inputs. It would help if you could add more information on that.

Comment: you are probably missing the fact that NN are function approximator... from one domain to the other... and they need to be trained on those domains... you change the domain, you loose every property (probably better to explain the actual conditions you have, to look for a better solution)

Comment: How are `0` and `1` determined?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess from your question what you are trying to accomplish in detail, but you should carefully consider if that is necessary.

It's common practice to have an input layer of a fixed size that matches the structure of your data. You preprocess your data to match that shape.

In the domain of e.g. images this might mean:
If you have images of different resolutions, you could consider cropping, padding or resizing your inputs to a fixed size.

If there is a rationale behind this please clarify.